# C++ Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c++, escaping, string-literals

I want to create a string that contains all possible special chars.

However, the compiler gives me the warning *"Unrecognized escape sequence"* in this line:

```
wstring s=L".,;*:-_⁊#‘⁂‡…–«»¤¤¡=„+-¶~´:№\¯/?‽!¡-¢–”¥—†¿»¤{}«[-]()·^°$§%&«|⸗<´>²³£­€™℗@©®~µ´`'" + wstring(1,34);
```

Can anybody please tell me which one of the characters I may not add to this string the way I did?

Comment: this has nothing to do with Unicode escape

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to escape `\` as `\\`, otherwise `\¯` will be interpreted as an (invalid) escape sequence:

```
wstring s=L".,;*:-_⁊#‘⁂‡…–«»¤¤¡=„+-¶~´:№\\¯/?‽!¡-¢–”¥—†¿»¤{}«[-]()·^°$§%&«|⸗<´>²³£­€™℗@©®~µ´`'" + wstring(1,34);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) is a character string that has a different meaning than the literal characters themselves. [In C and C++ the sequence begins with `\`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) so if your string contains a double quote or backslash it must be escaped properly using `\"` and `\\`

In long copy-pasted strings it may be difficult to spot those characters and it's also less maintainable in the future so it's recommended to use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with the prefix `R` so you don't need any escapes at all

```
wstring s = LR"(.,;*:-_⁊#‘⁂‡…–«»¤¤¡=„+-¶~´:№\¯/?‽!¡-¢–”¥—†¿»¤{}«[-]()·^°$§%&«|⸗<´>²³£­€™℗@©®~µ´`')"
          + wstring(1,34);
```

A special delimiter string may be inserted outside the parentheses like this `LR"delim(special string)delim"` in case your raw string contains a `)"` sequence